# Linq return NullReferenceException when list have null values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a list of Customer details,and some customer's Mobile_No is null,when I run the below code its throws a NullReferenceException because of null values,haw can I get this list with null values?

```
    public IList<CustomerMdl> AddSupplier_gridCustomer()
    {
     var ShopModel = icustomerrepository.GetList(x => x.Customer_Id != 0)
            .Select(y => new CustomerMdl
            {
                Customer_Id = y.Customer_Id,
                Customer_Name = y.Customer_Name,
                RouteName = y.Route.RouteName,
                Customer_TypeName = y.Customer_Types.Customer_Type_Name,
                Customer_GradeName = y.Customer_Grades.Customer_Grade_Description,
                Land_No=y.Land_No,
                Mobile_No=y.Mobile_No,
                VAT = true,
                NBT = true,      
                Active=y.Active,
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Customer_Name).ToList();
        return ShopModel;
    }
```

Comment: Yes,its  throws a null reference exception because some customer's Mobile_No is Null

Comment: I can't set y.Mobile_No to null,because some customer's have Mobile_No,I want to get that